# the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am trying to create some code that determines if the a and the B are in the exact same place on a 2D array (referred to as `gameBoard`), regardless on where about they meet.

Now I tried to do this by creating two separate integers (called row and column) that increment over the `BoardWidth` and the `BoardHeight` (which are constant integers set to 10), but I keep getting the error that *"the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer."*

Now while I believe this error is occurring because of the way that the if statement is written, but I don't know what I can do to change without breaking functionality.

Here's my code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < BoardWidth; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < BoardHeight; column++)
    {
        if (gameBoard[row, column] == "a" = gameBoard[row, column] == "B")//Where the error is
        {
            //To be written once the error is fixed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here `"a" = gameBoard[row, column]` the `=` is wrong. Perhaps it should be `||`

Comment: You've got invalid syntax in your if statement. `=` (a single equals) is the assignment operator. You clearly can't assign `gameBoard[row, column] == "B"` to `"a"`, because `"a"` is a constant.

Comment: Maybe that should be `if ((gameBoard[row, column] == "a") = (gameBoard[row, column] == "B"))`?  Not sure if C# accepts that, I know older languages will.

Comment: As a note: You can't *break functionality* of code that won't even compile, because there *is* no functionality until it does and the code can be run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because of the `=` assignment operator in your `IF` condition as pointed below

```
if (gameBoard[row, column] == "a" = gameBoard[row, column] == "B")
                                  ^....Here
```

I think you meant to use a `||` OR condition like

```
if (gameBoard[row, column] == "a" || gameBoard[row, column] == "B")
```

Comment: From the text, I think it would be an AND that the OP is looking for here.

Comment: @KenWhite, how can `gameBoard[row, column]` be `a` and `B` simultaneously at same time? You are referring to text in post `if the a and the B are in the exact same place` but I am not sure

Comment: You're right. I have no idea what the OP is looking to do here, after reading it again.

Answer (score 1):

`gameBoard[row, column] == "a" = gameBoard[row, column] == "B"` evaluates to `true/false = true/false`. Since assigning a value to `true/false` doesn't make sense, you get an error.

Comment: So that's why it was having a paddy at me. Thank you for your guidence

Answer (score 0):

```
if (gameBoard[row, column] == "a" = gameBoard[row, column] == "B")
```

Here you have a `=` (an assignment) between your two checks.

I think you want to check if the content of `gameBoard[row, column]` is *a* **or** *B*.
To do this you have to change the `=` to `||`

```
if (gameBoard[row, column] == "a" || gameBoard[row, column] == "B")
```